# How can I run a program that uses JFileChooser class from the command prompt?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to compile a program that uses the `JFileChooser` class in Java from command prompt.  My question is that if there is any type of a generic argument I can use for `showOpenDialog()` as a component to open a dialogue box.  Here's a sample code:

```
  public class FileChooser{
      public static void main(String args[]) {
              JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
          FileReader reader= null;
          Scanner scanner= null;

          int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
          if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
              File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
              try{
              reader = new FileReader(file);
              } catch (IOException io){
                  System.out.println("File not found");
              }
              scanner = new Scanner (reader);   
              scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
              String s = scanner.next();
              System.out.println(s);

              }

              scanner.close();
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are asking for [showOpenDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) argument (not JFileChooser constructor argument). You can use null. See [JFileChooser.showDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String%29) for more details.
Here's the code you need

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Comment: That is right (I edited my question).  I have already used JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(null), but the code does nt compile.

Comment: @Kambiz You don't need to supply an argument to the `JFileChooser` constructor.  Just use the default, zero-argument one.

Comment: I meant you don't need pass an argument to the constructor. You the default, but add null to the showOpenDialog() method.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I just noticed that I used null as a constructor for JFileChooser and used no argument for showOpenDialog (corrected). In addition, I was prompted to initialize the variables reader and scanner to null (all edited above). Thanks a lot!